# What is pull up and pull down resistor in microcontroller

Tags: embedded

Why pull up and pull down resister is connected to the pin.
how to configure pin as pull up and pull down or as interrupt souce.

Comment: You want to read up a bit before touching anything. These are the most basic concepts you have to understand.

Comment: I asked this question because many of the programmer program this things but don't know the actual core electronics part of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an output, it gives the pin a defined logic state when the GPIO is in the reset state which is normally a high impedance input, so is not driving the output to a valid logic state.

For an input the need for it is determined by the attached device, which may also be high-impedence or "floating" on start-up, in which case the pull-up/down will ensure a valid level.

Devices with open-drain/open-collector outputs will need a pull-up/down.

You will need at least a basic understanding of electronics to be successful in embedded systems development (unless all you need happens to be on one off-the-shelf board without modifications or additions.  Get yourself a copy of *Horowitz & Hill's The Art of Electronics* or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Some devices by design can only drive a 1 or drive a 0 and some can drive both.  Where you would use something like that is a shared line like spi for example, if you are the device being addressed you pull zero, only one device pulls a zero at a time.  Since the line is either floating or zero to make it a one the rest of the time you need a pull up resistor, think of it as a ball or something on a spring the spring keeps the ball up near the ceiling, when you need the ball on the ground it is pulled down against the spring, the spring is fairly weak. when the ball is released the spring pulls it back up to the ceiling.  Similar thing on these kinds of busses.